# Pandas Delete String from 1 dataframe if it exist in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with keywords and a list of words which if exist in that data frame then should be deleted.

**Only the word should be deleted not the column or row from the data frame.**

Here is the Dataframe I have. I have a list of words as well as a pandas series of it. I want to drop only the words which are on that list from the keywords.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmOTS.png)

Comment: It will be better if you can post your data frame and your expected data frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete rows based on list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46978264/1278112)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['www.test.com', ['test', 'joke']],
                   ['www.google.com', ['jacket', 'coffee', 'second']],
                   ['www.stackoverflow.com', ['word', 'another']]],
                   columns = ['URL', 'keywords'])

values = ['test', 'ten', 'second', 'stackoverflow']


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for word in row['keywords']:
        if word in values:
            row['keywords'].remove(word)

print(df)

#output

                     URL          keywords
0           www.test.com            [joke]
1         www.google.com  [jacket, coffee]
2  www.stackoverflow.com   [word, another]
```

Comment: This code gives every single value from the dataframe. But unable to enter the if statement.

Comment: Works for me. See the full example given. Update above.

Comment: I did not want to delete the whole row. Want to delete just the keyword from its list.

Comment: @karancraze. Now try it

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. You saved me.